# Trying to learn addEventListener and my code isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a magic 8 ball. I've added the answers at the top in an array, added the code to choose a random answer, and when the button is clicked, it's supposed to place said random answer in a p tag in a div. It actually worked very well a few times in codePen and then stopped. I didn't change a thing. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing if anything?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>8 Ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball">
        <div id="display">

          <p id="output"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
      <button id="button">Answer</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var answers = ["Yes!", "Absolutely!", "Not A Chance", "No", 
"Ask Me Later", "Not Yet"];

//random answer function displays random in the output id
var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
 }

 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

I've tried moving things around and looking addEventListener up. There's a few questions here on that, too, but I haven't found anything that solves my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reordering the placement of your `<script>` tag in you HTML , so that the script is run after the DOM is loaded/parsed. 
When your script is run, the `button` that you're trying to add a click listener to is not going to be present because the script is run from the `<head>` tag before the `<body>` DOM contents are loaded and ready.

Try the following adjustment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>8 Ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball">
        <div id="display">

          <p id="output"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
      <button id="button">Answer</button>

    <!-- Put script here instead -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, consider revising your javascript so the the randomAnswer is recomputed each time the user clicks the button, so that the answer shown to the answer is able to change per button click:

```
var answers = ["Yes!", "Absolutely!", "Not A Chance", "No", 
"Ask Me Later", "Not Yet"];

function myFunction(){

    //[UPDATE] Move the random answer computation inside of myFunction()
    var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
 }

 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Comment: That explains why it worked in codePen and not in Visual Studio Code. Made changes and it works well now.

Comment: @N.Saunders great to hear - glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Your script is loaded in the header. It's executed whereas the page didnt finished to load, so you're trying to attach a listener to the button element that doesnt exist yet. Move it to the bottom of the body section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    // deleted
    <title>8 Ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball">
        <div id="display">
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="button">Answer</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script> // pasted here
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `randomAnswer` needs to be defined **inside** of the function, so that the answer gets decided upon each time you press the button. Outside of the function it gets defined on page load, and the answer will be the same each time.

Here's an updated snippet:

```js
var answers = ["Yes!", "Absolutely!", "Not A Chance", "No",
  "Ask Me Later", "Not Yet"
];

function myFunction() {
  //random answer function displays random in the output id
  var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>8 Ball</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ball">
    <div id="display">

      <p id="output"></p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button id="button">Answer</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

`//random answer function displays random in the output id
var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];`

inside of your function like this:

`function myFunction(){
    var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction=()=>{

  //[UPDATE] Move the random answer computation inside of myFunction()
  var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
});
```

Place the logic inside the function and it will be created everytime that it is called.
Or ou could assign the function to a variable like this:

```
var answers = ["Yes!", "Absolutely!", "Not A Chance", "No",
"Ask Me Later", "Not Yet"];

    let myFunction = function(){

    //[UPDATE] Move the random answer computation inside of myFunction()
    var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = randomAnswer;
    }

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```